# How to randomise a list of URL's in PHP using ACF?

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have a web page that calls in 7 images from wordpress using an ACF Repeater field.

What I want to do is get the list of URL's of the images and then shuffle them so that they images will appear randomly on the webpage. When I call the images with `($image['url'])` , the only image that is displayed is the last image uploaded to the wordpress site.

```
<?php       
    // Call the ACF Gallery images 
    $imageArray = get_field('company_logos', 13);
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

    if( $imageArray ):
        while( have_rows('company_logos', 13) ) : the_row();
             $image = get_sub_field('image');
            // $content = get_sub_field('content');

              //shuffle ($image['url']);

              $arr = $image['url'];
              shuffle($arr);
              print_r($arr);

        endwhile;
        endif; ?>
```

When I echo out the images URL's to the screen they come out in the format of:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/a.jpg
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/b.png
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/c.jpg
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/d.jpg
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/e.jpg
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/f.jpg
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/g.jpg
```

Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Apologies for the first post, does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get the list of images from $image['url']? Does it return an array in the first place? If it does then your solution should work. If it is not an array but a string of URLs separated by comma then, do the following before the 2nd statement. So, the new code would look like as follows,

```
$urls = $image['url'];
$arr = explode(" ", $urls);
shuffle($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Apologies for the first post, does this make more sense? I tired you're solution but it didn't work..